# Altura del contenido correcta

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

i quiero que el header tenga la altura por defecto (con un padding que le pongo) y el footer un 10%, como hago para que el contenido me ocupe el resto para que todo en conjunto sea el 100% de la página? Si le pongo al contenido un 80% el header es mas de un 10% y ya hay que hacer scroll y es lo que estoy intentando que no pase.

[image: 5]

Answer (score 1):

**Te comparto un ejemplo que cumple con lo siguiente:**

- El **header** puede tener un alto dinámico.
- El **footer** tendrá un alto del **10%** relativo al alto de la ventana.
- El **content** tendrá un alto variable pero siempre tratara de ocupar todo el espacio disponible del resto entre el alto dinámico del header y el footer.

**Ejemplo online:** https://jsfiddle.net/chenay01/25hd90Lc/13

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}

section {
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

footer {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 10vh;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<section>content</section>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Para este ejemplo utilice el diseño flexible "[flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout)" y las medidas relativas de acuerdo al viewport [(vh/vw)](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/unidades-vh-vw-css/) de **CSS3**.

Comment: Tu respuesta es muy buena para lo que solicita David, pero para que tu diseño quede como el de la imagen que muestra él deberías agregar la propiedad de `width:50%;` y  `margin: auto;` para centrar la caja en el section para el contenido.